# Send a UDP message to another network using socket

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, udp, send

I've been making a sample program wherein the user can broadcast messages using **sockets** and **UDP** connection. It was successful in LAN but I can't broadcast my messages to other networks (e.g. 10.15.1.11's message to 10.11.1.23). Here's my sample code:

**Listener:**

bworker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

```
        Socket _ListenerSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);

        IPEndPoint _ListenerEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, _port);
        _ListenerSocket.EnableBroadcast = true;
        _ListenerSocket.Bind(_ListenerEndPoint);
        //_ListenerSocket.Connect(MulticastIP, _port);
        _ListenerSocket.Ttl = 255;
        _ListenerSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.AddMembership, new MulticastOption(MulticastIP));

        while (true)
        {
            byte[] msg = new byte[1024];
            _ListenerSocket.Receive(msg);
            string StringData = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(msg);
            bworker.ReportProgress(0, StringData);
        }
```

**Sender:**

```
Socket _ClientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
            _ClientSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.AddMembership, new MulticastOption(MulticastIP));

        _ClientSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.MulticastTimeToLive, int.Parse(ttl));

        IPEndPoint _ClientEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(MulticastIP, _port);

        _ClientSocket.Connect(_ClientEndPoint);

        byte[] MsgByte = new byte[1024];
        MsgByte = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(txtmsg.Text);
        _ClientSocket.Send(MsgByte);
```

**Variables:**

```
public const int _port = 8041;        
public const string ttl = "255";
public IPAddress MulticastIP = IPAddress.Parse("239.0.0.222");
```

Thanks.

Comment: The router between you and the other LAN probably refuses to forward packets with multicast destination IPs.

Comment: Hi, is there a way to check if the router between me and the other LAN refuses to forward packets? Thanks.

Comment: The simplest approach is to send the packet to a unicast destination (the actual IP address of a destination machine), then check if it arrived.

Comment: I guess to ping the destination is one way. The destination can receive the packets. But still It can't receive my messages.

Comment: You can simply try changing the ip in the IPEndPoint to the destination's IP. Ping uses completely different messages, so it wont tell you whether the problem is with the multicast destination.

Comment: I just tried it but it also won't go to the destination.

Answer (score 0):

The router between you and the other LAN probably refuses to forward packets with multicast destination IPs. To handle multicast properly, the router itself has to be multicast-aware and implement protocols such as [PIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_Independent_Multicast) (for coordinating multicast between routers) and [IGMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Group_Management_Protocol) (for coordinating multicast with end-hosts)

Comment: Can I still ping the destination even though the router between you and the other LAN refuses to forward packets? Thanks

Comment: It's probably refusing to forward packets to MULTICAST ip addresses. Regular (unicast) ip addresses should work fine, and therefore ping should work fine.

Comment: I just tried unicast and it still the destination can't receive the message, but ping does.

Answer (score 0):

Your router probably doesn't forward multicast packages. In order for multicast to work all routers along the path of communication must me multicast enabled. Ping only requires the router to forward ping packages so that will really only tell you if you can reach the other computer at all. Take a look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1705/IP-Multicasting-in-C) article to learn more about multicasting in C#.